# how is using filter a bad-builtin?

Tags: python

This might be a basic question but  I curious to know if I am using filter builtin in my code but pylint reports

`W: 67,13: Used builtin function 'filter' (bad-builtin)`

how come thats bad-builtin ?

Comment: Long story short, going forward you should prefer List comprehension instead of `filter`. pylint enforces this with this error message.

Comment: feel free to ignore it, especially if it tells you `map` is bad.  `map` is awesome.

Comment: @roippi But we should not use `map` also. List comprehension is the way to go :)

Comment: @thefourtheye we'll just have to agree to disagree, this comment box is insufficient space for me to extol the virtues of `map` :)

Comment: performance wise is it list comprehension better or the builtin `map` ?

Comment: Depends. See this answer for some old test data: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map - but either way the choice is almost certainly not what's going to determine your overall performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to decide whether you care about this warning or not.

```
filter(my_filter, my_iterable)
```

is equivalent to:

```
[item for item in my_iterable if my_filter(item)]
```

In python 3, `filter` acts like a generator, which means that it lazily evaluates things, e.g.:

```
(item for item in my_iterable if my_filter(item))
```

I would ignore this particular warning.  Pyflakes may give you a more useful output.